# TYPO3 TCA Defalut text multiline/textarea

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Can i set a default "multiline value" for textareas in TYPO3 TCA ?

if i use `\n` for example the output is always `\n` not a linebreak. The "Default" tag is an integer or String (TYPO3 docu), so it seems not to be possible to enter a default multilined text to a textarea right?

```
<config>
    <type>text</type>
    <rows>3</rows>
    <cols>30</cols>
    <eval>trim</eval>
    <default>WILD AND FREE \n SINCE 2008</default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to adapt to the kind of definition you use.

In general TCA is defined in a PHP file, but you use XML. XML don't know about escaped characters like `\n`. but the content of tags could include linebreaks, so it would be possible to split the `default` tag and end it some lines later.
Be aware of indentions!